# Bolt CMS not returning response

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, vagrant, bolt-cms

I am running the bolt cms on a vagrant virtual machine. I have configured my mod_rewrite properly according to the tutorial but once I want to go to the site I get an error reponse in chrome and getting this response ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE. When I phpinfo in my index.php it is working but when I want to run bolt it will give me back the error.

Comment: There can be many different causes, we probably do not have information to help you here.

Comment: I am not aware of Bolt CMS but I know Vagrant and Symfony. Could you provide more logs please? Ideally `/app/log/dev.log` or `/app/log/prod.log` if Bolt has them, plus your web server's error log and/or PHP-FPM error log?

Comment: have you changed the permissions for all the directories according to the installation instructions?

Answer (score 0):

I found out the problem. It had to do with my setup I was using xDebug on a virtual machine but it had not enough memory so it ran out of memory. Disabling xDebug on my virtual machine worked for me.

Comment: Wow, respect for answering your own question after 4 years :)

Comment: Haha, I looked "Nov 11" and I thought it was 2011 ;) Well, congrats anyway!